# From C to GMP implementation

Tags: c, gmp

I would ask you how this code written in c would look in GMP. I tried something to write but the library is hard to understand. I don't know how to write operation: `r = r*10 + n%10;` in gmp. I would be very grateful for help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <gmp.h>

long long rev(long long n)
{
    long long r = 0;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        r = r*10 + n%10;
        n = n/10;
    }
    return r;
}

bool palindrome(long long n)
{
    return (rev(n) == n);
}

void reverseAdd(long long n)
{
    long long r=0;
    while (n <= 100000000000000)
    {
        r = rev(n);
        printf("stage: %lld + %lld\n",n,r); 

        n = n + r;

        if (palindrome(n))
        {
            printf("Palindrom: %lld\n",n);
            break;
        }
        else if (n > 100000000000000)
        {
            printf("Not a palindrome\n");
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    long long l;

    printf("Give the number to analyze:");
    scanf("%lld",&l);
    reverseAdd(l);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to use long literals.

Comment: Decimal `100000000000000000000000000` is hex `DCC80CD2E4000000` which only fits `**unsigned** long long` 64 bit type.

Comment: I mean that, "n" might be written in gmp

Comment: correct code indentation

Comment: You'll need to do what the compiler does — break down computations into operations.  Each operation will be a GMP function call.  Initialization, comparison, assignment, computation, convert to string, convert from string, etc.  Find the right function calls and use appropriately.

Comment: @MariannaKalwat Could you post the C code for `palindrome(...)`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print `mpz_t` variables use `gmp_printf`. GMP adds types `‘Z’`, `‘Q’` and `‘F’` for `mpz_t, mpq_t and mpf_t` respectively.

```
The GMP types are:

F   mpf_t, float conversions
Q   mpq_t, integer conversions
M   mp_limb_t, integer conversions
N   mp_limb_t array, integer conversions
Z   mpz_t, integer conversions
```

`gmp_printf` accepts format strings similar to the standard C `printf` (see [**Formatted Output**](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Formatted-Output.html#Formatted-Output) in The GNU C Library Reference Manual).

Referring to your last question and your posted program, you can use `gmp_printf` to print `l`.
 See the program modified below:

```
//....

int main()
{
   int k;
    mpz_t l;
    mpz_t n;
    mpz_init (n);  /* remember to init mpz variables */
    mpz_init (l);

    printf("Number to analysis: ");
    gmp_scanf("%Zd",l);

    gmp_printf ("%s the mpz number %Zd\n", "You have entered", l);

    do
    {
        mpz_set(n, l);
        analyzeAdd(n);
        mpz_add_ui(l,l,1);

     }while(false);

    gmp_printf ("%s is equal %Zd\n", "Now the n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Number to analysis: 123321
You have entered the mpz number 123321
Now the n is equal 246642
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to read some tutorials on GMP.

For example:

[**GMP Tutorial**](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~srirams/courses/csci2824-spr14/gmpTutorial.html)

[**Advanced GMP Tutorial**](https://gmplib.org/gmp-man-6.0.0a.pdf)

[**Code examples per gmp function**](http://sepwww.stanford.edu/sep/claudio/Research/Prst_ExpRefl/ShtPSPI/intel/mkl/10.0.3.020/examples/gmp/source/) - my favorite!

[**More  GMP Examples**](https://www.mitchr.me/SS/exampleCode/GMP.html)

Some simple functions in GMP:

```
mpz_t t; // this is the type of statement is needed to declare a variable
mpz_init (t); // initialization of a variable
mpz_set_ui (t, 2); // assignment of 2 to already initialized variable t
mpz_set_str (t, "1234"); // string assignment
mpz_add (t, a , b); // a + b is assigned to t, that is, t = a + b
mpz_sub (t, a, b); // subtraction
mpz_mul (t, a, b); // multiplication
gmp_printf ("% Zd ", t); // print output t
```

A simple GMP program:

```
#include <gmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(){

  /* The basic operation is to initialize the number */
  /* 1. Initialize the number r */
  mpz_t r;
  mpz_init(r);
  mpz_set_ui(r,15);   /*r = 15 now */

  mpz_mul_ui(r,r,10); /* r = r * 10 */

  printf (" r = ");
  mpz_out_str(stdout,10,r);
  printf ("\n");

}
```

`r = r * 10 + n % 10;`  has to be done in steps:

```
mpz_mul_ui(r,r,10); /* r = r * 10 */

mpz_mod_ui(n,n,10); /* n = n % 10 */

mpz_add(r,r,n);     /* r = r + n */ /* r = r * 10 + n % 10 */
```

`mpz_t` variable can be used as a function parameter.

Quoting from documentation:
When a variable of type `mpz_t` is used as a function parameter, it's effectively a call-by-reference, meaning anything the function does to it will be be done to the original in the caller. When a function is going to return an `mpz_t` result, it should provide a separate parameter or parameters that it sets, like the GMP library functions do. A return of an `mpz_t` doesn't return the object, only a pointer to it, and this is almost certainly not what you want. All this applies to `mpq_t` and `mpf_t` too.

Here's an example function accepting an `mpz_t` parameter, doing a certain calculation, and returning a result.

```
void
myfunction (mpz_t result, mpz_t param, unsigned long n)
{
  unsigned long  i;

  mpz_mul_ui (result, param, n);
  for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    mpz_add_ui (result, result, i*7);
}

int
main (void)
{
  mpz_t  r, n;
  mpz_init (r);
  mpz_init_set_str (n, "123456", 0);

  myfunction (r, n, 20L);
  mpz_out_str (stdout, 10, r); printf ("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

This example will work if result and param are the same variable, just like the library functions. But sometimes this is tricky to arrange, and an application might not want to bother for its own subroutines.

Example: How to reverse the number using GMP:

```
void rev(mpz_t r, mpz_t param, mpz_t n)
{
    mpz_t nm10;        /* introduce temporary variable to hold n%10 result */ 
    mpz_init (nm10);  /* init */

    mpz_set_ui(r,0);  /* set r to 0 */

    /*    Call mpz_cmp_ui to compare op1 and op2.                        */
    /*    Return a positive value if op1 > op2, zero if op1 = op2,       */
    /*            or a negative value if op1 < op2                       */
    /*                                                                   */

    while ( mpz_cmp_ui(n,0) > 0)  /*    Call mpz_cmp_ui to compare op1 and op2 */
    {
        mpz_mul_ui(r,param,10);  /* r = r * 10  */

        mpz_mod_ui(nm10,n,10);   /* nm10 = n%10 */

        mpz_add(r,r,nm10);       /* r = r*10 + n%10; */

        mpz_div_ui(n,n,10);      /* n = n/10 */
    }
}

void reverseAdd(mpz_t n)
{
       mpz_t r;
       mpz_init (r);

       mpz_set_ui(r,0);

       mpz_out_str(stdout,10,n); printf ("  n: input value \n");

       rev(r, r, n);

       mpz_out_str(stdout,10,n);
       printf ("      n: after calculations value \n");

       mpz_out_str(stdout,10,r);
       printf ("  r: reversed value\n");

}

int main()
{
    mpz_t l;
    mpz_init (l);

    printf("Give number to analyze:");
    gmp_scanf("%Zd",l);

    reverseAdd(l);

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
 Give number to analyze:12345
 12345  n: input value 
 0      n: after calculations value 
 54321  r: reversed value
```

Example: Check if given number is a Palindrome:

```
void rev(mpz_t r, mpz_t param, mpz_t n)
{
    mpz_t nm10;        /* introduce temporary variable to hold n%10 result */
    mpz_init (nm10);  /* init */

    mpz_set_ui(r,0);  /* set r to 0 */

    while ( mpz_cmp_ui(n,0) > 0)  /*    Call mpz_cmp_ui to compare op1 and op2 */
    {
        mpz_mul_ui(r,param,10);  /* r = r * 10  */
        mpz_mod_ui(nm10,n,10);   /* nm10 = n%10 */
        mpz_add(r,r,nm10);       /* r = r*10 + n%10; */
        mpz_div_ui(n,n,10);      /* n = n/10 */
    }
}

void analyze(mpz_t n)
{
       mpz_t r;
       mpz_init (r);

       mpz_t input;
       mpz_init (input);

       mpz_set(input, n);  /* remember the input */

       mpz_out_str(stdout,10,n);
       printf ("  n: input value \n");

       rev(r, r, n);

       mpz_out_str(stdout,10,r);
       printf ("  r: reversed value value\n");

       if (  mpz_cmp(input,r) == 0) {
            mpz_out_str(stdout,10,input);
            printf("  is a Palindrome! \n");
       }
       else{
            printf("The input number was not a Palindrome.\n");
       }
 }

int main()
{
    mpz_t l;
    mpz_init (l);

    printf("Give number to analyze: ");
    gmp_scanf("%Zd",l);

    analyze(l);

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Give number to analyze: 123454321
123454321  n: input value 
123454321  r: reversed value value
123454321  is a Palindrome!
```

**This is equivalent of the Marianna's C code using loop and GMP implementation:**

```
void rev(mpz_t r, mpz_t n)
{
    mpz_t nm10;       /* introduce temporary variable to hold n%10 result */
    mpz_init (nm10);  /* init */

    mpz_t nn;
    mpz_init (nn);   /* init */

    mpz_set(nn, n);   /* do not use n  directly, use nn for divisions '/' */
    mpz_set_ui(r,0);  /* set r to 0! */

    while ( mpz_cmp_ui(nn,0) > 0)  /*    Call mpz_cmp_ui to compare op1 and op2 */
    {
        mpz_mul_ui(r,r,10);      /* r = r * 10  */
        mpz_mod_ui(nm10,nn,10);  /* nm10 = n%10 */
        mpz_add(r,r,nm10);       /* r = r*10 + n%10; */
        mpz_div_ui(nn,nn,10);    /* n = n/10 */
    }
}

bool palindrome(mpz_t r, mpz_t n)
{
    /* calculate the reverse number */
    rev(r, n);
    return( (mpz_cmp(r,n) == 0));
}

void analyzeAdd(mpz_t n)
{
    mpz_t r;
    mpz_init (r);

    mpz_set_ui(r,0);  /* set r to 0! */

/* loop */

    while (1)
    {
       int compare = mpz_cmp_ui(n,100000000000000);
        /*    Return a positive value if op1 > op2, zero if op1 = op2,       */
        /*    or a negative value if op1 < op2                               */

       if (compare > 0)
       {
         printf("Not a palindrome!\n");
         break; /* break the while loop */
       }

       rev(r, n); /* r is returned, n is not modified */

       printf("stage:  ");
       mpz_out_str(stdout,10,n);
       printf(" + ");
       mpz_out_str(stdout,10,r);
       printf("\n");

       /*  !!!  */
       mpz_add(n,n,r); /*   n = n + r; */


       if (palindrome(r,n))
       {
            printf("Palindrome: ");
            mpz_out_str(stdout,10,n);
            printf("\n");

            break;
        }
        else if ( mpz_cmp_ui(n,100000000000000) > 0 )
        {
            printf("Not a palindrome\n");
        }
    }/*while*/
}

int main()
{
    mpz_t l;
    mpz_init (l);

    printf("Give number to analyze: ");
    gmp_scanf("%Zd",l);

    analyzeAdd(l);

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

a)

```
Give number to analyze: 77
stage:  77 + 77
stage:  154 + 451
stage:  605 + 506
Palindrome: 1111
```

b)

```
Give number to analyze: 123456788999000 
Not a palindrome!
```

Comment: But how to write this "r = r*10 + n%10;" in gmp?

Comment: @MariannaKalwat "r = r*10 + n%10;" added above.

Comment: I didn't know that it must be in several steps. Thank you ;) But i don't know what to do with "long long rev(long long n)"?

Comment: @MariannaKalwat You can return result as `mpz_t result` as in function `myfunction` above. I suggest to read more documentation, try to write and debug small programs and analyze gmp sample examples. Process of learning requires great deal of self studies.

Comment: I've write in gmp but i've two errors and two warnings. What i have to correct in my code?

Comment: @MariannaKalwat Full solution in gmp is given. Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you very much for help ;) I wanted to loop the program to reverse and add until get a palindrome

Comment: How can i get a loop in this program to reverse and add until get a palindrome?

Comment: @MariannaKalwat I take a look at it later on when I get back to my computer...What is inside C function   `if(palindrome(n))` ? The gmp version is incorrect there is no bool value returned and it does not check anything.

Comment: @MariannaKalwat Full solution added with `while` loop! Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted that program would show OUTPUT when k > 20 like this, for example:

```
Number: 89 Number of stage: 24 Palindrome: 8813200023188
```

And it's ok because k = 24.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <gmp.h>

void rev(mpz_t r, mpz_t n)
{
    mpz_t nm10;
    mpz_init (nm10);

    mpz_t nn;
    mpz_init (nn);

    mpz_set(nn, n);
    mpz_set_ui(r,0);

    while ( mpz_cmp_ui(nn,0) > 0)
    {
        mpz_mul_ui(r,r,10);      /* r = r * 10  */
        mpz_mod_ui(nm10,nn,10);  /* nm10 = n%10 */
        mpz_add(r,r,nm10);       /* r = r*10 + n%10; */
        mpz_div_ui(nn,nn,10);    /* n = n/10 */
    }
}

bool palindrome(mpz_t r, mpz_t n)
{
    rev(r, n);
    return( (mpz_cmp(r,n) == 0));
}

void analyzeAdd(mpz_t n)
{
    mpz_t l;
    mpz_t r;
    mpz_init (r);

    mpz_set_ui(r,0);

    int k = 0;

    while (1)
    {

       k = k + 1;

       if (k > 400)
       {
         /*printf("It's not a palindrome!\n");*/
         break;
       }

       rev(r, n);

       /*printf("Krok:  ");
       mpz_out_str(stdout,10,n);
       printf(" + ");
       mpz_out_str(stdout,10,r);
       printf("\n");*/


       mpz_add(n,n,r); /*   n = n + r; */


       if (palindrome(r,n))
       {
            if (k > 20) {
            printf("Number of stage: %d ",k);
            printf("Palindrome: ");
            mpz_out_str(stdout,10,n);


            printf("\n");
            }

            break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    mpz_t l;
    mpz_t n;
    mpz_init (l);

    printf("Give number: ");
    gmp_scanf("%Zd",l);

do
{
       mpz_set(n, l);
       gmp_printf("Number: %Zd \n",l);
       analyzeAdd(n);
       mpz_add_ui(l,l,1);


}while(1);



    return 0;
}
```